# Why isn't Ubuntu 14.04 shutting down?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, shutdown

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto an Asus X554S laptop. When I click the restart of shutdown button, it starts shutting down, but after a bit of loading (showing that purple loading screen) it just simply stops and never finishes shutting down. I have to manually turn the computer off, after which if I want to turn it on again, it doesn't reboot, only if I repeat the process (turn off then on) once more.

I have tried the following:

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"` (no result)
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"` (no result)
- removed the `quiet splash` part so I could see what's happening (I'm not sure if I did that right), but the plymouth screen still appeared (before anyone asks, I did update-grub after each attempt)
- blacklist wistron_btns (no result)
- `sudo poweroff` (yields the same result; well, more bulbs light up on the plymouth screen, but I don't think that's progress)
- Cairo Dock is not installed (I remember it used to cause similar problems for some people)
- connects to wireless network perfectly and has internet access (so my guess is it's not a network issue, although I could be wrong)
- I have had no graphic issues until I removed "quiet splash" from GRUB, then upon booting it showed text, but the numbers and letters were unintelligible (maybe an issue with the Nvidia driver?)

What else can I do?

EDIT: In the process, for reasons beyond my comprehension, the touchpad stopped working. Now neither `xinput --list` nor `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` shows any signs of it. I did install a pack of updates recommended by the system, though (which might have solved my initial problem without my knowing, see below).

Nevertheless, I did update my nvidia driver using `sudo apt install nvidia-340 -y`, after which it did shut down properly. Restarting the machine, however, proved troublesome, as bbswitch found no discrete VGA device. Not even my mouse was usable. So, I used `sudo apt purge nvidia*`, after which my computer did reboot. I tried `nvidia-352` just to see what happens, but the results were the same: successful shutdown, no discrete VGA device. So I purged that as well.

Now the situation is rather peculiar as I find no graphical errors, the system shuts down and powers off properly, yet my touchpad is still undetected. I guess that deserves a question of its own. I'll still leave this one unsolved for now until I'm absolutely sure the problem doesn't creep back in somehow.

Comment: I had the same problem with 16.04.  Try installing Nvidia driver. It solved my problem.

Comment: Tried that; edited post with results.

Comment: I cannot find your laptop in Asus website, but if it is new (or even it is not), maybe there is a problem with BIOS. Try update it and set it to default. In addition why don't you try installing 16.04 and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd. I've heard about this issue before, but assumed it was fixed in the newer versions of Ubuntu.

Can you give the following command a shot and let me know what happens?

`sudo init 0`